# Find unique number in array in fill list with this unique numbers using for loops

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, console-application

I'm trying to use for loop inside for loop but it doesn't working i also tried while loop but...

```
int[] numArray = new int[10] {1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,9};
List<Int32> uNum = new List<Int32>();
/*Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    numArray[i] = randomNumber;
}*/
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (numArray[i] != numArray[i])
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numArray.Length-1; j++)
        {
            if (numArray[i] != numArray[j])
            {
                uNum.Add(numArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need output like  (1,9) because of other numbers are repeating

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this line:

```
if (numArray[i] != numArray[i])
```

This condition will always return False because a number is always equal to itself.

Do something like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<numArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j=0; i<numArray.Length; j++){
         if (i != j){
            if (numArray[i] != numArray[j])
             {
                uNum.Add(numArray[i]);
             }
          }
        }
          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numArray = new int[10];
List<Int32> uNum = new List<Int32>();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    numArray[i] = randomNumber;
}
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
{
    int num = numArray[i];
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (numArray[j] == num)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        uNum.Add(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).